# Time Machine for Multiple standard user accounts on the same mac

Tags: security, user-account

I have multiple standard user accounts on a Mac OS computer.

I have removed read and execute privileges for group and other on each home folder.

This is because I do not want users to see other user's home content.

It works but my admin account cannot see user's home folder too. This is fine but do you think timemachine will be able to backup all homes folder ?

Please note the Time Machine backup will be launched by a standard user.

Thanks

Comment: User folders default to not being able to be accessed from other accounts. I don't know what you think you needed to do to change this, or what you might have broken in the process. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VEYs.png Time Machine runs with higher privileges than any user, so **at defaults** it should be just fine. With random permissions changes, it's hard to know.

Comment: You can try: Create 2 standard users: You will see you can access to their home directories. You cannot access to subfolder but you can see content of home

Comment: Of course you can see into Home - otherwise you couldn't reach the Public or web folders. This is shown in my screenshot above. Users should not be putting *anything* at that level in Home, they should be using the sub-folders.

Comment: I do not care about Public and web folders. I just want timemachine working. I've done a chmod go-rx /Users/user1. Do you think timemachine will work ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. Try it & see. Playing with Home folder perms is not advisable, so I'm not going to test it.

Comment: I have tried. It seems to work but I am not serene... Thanks